# Python dataframe groupby, then count where based on values in group

Tags: python, group-by, count, conditional-statements

Edited to include Country:
I have a Python dataframe looking like this:

| Indicator | Value | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 | x |
| A | 20 | x |
| A | 30 | x |
| B | 10 | x |
| B | 30 | y |
| B | 20 | z |

data = ([ { "Indicator": "A", "Country": "x",  "Value": 20 }, { "Indicator": "A", "Country": "x","Value": 20 }, { "Indicator": "A","Country": "x", "Value": 30 },
{ "Indicator": "B","Country": "x", "Value": 10 }, { "Indicator": "B","Country": "y","Value": 30 }, { "Indicator": "B", "Country": "y", "Value": 20 }])

Then I want to do a groupby Indicator, and create a new column that do a calculation on the Value per group:
Count how many times Value <= other Values in the Indicator-Country group.
This output shoud be added as a new column Rank, and the output should then represent this:

| Indicator | Value | Country | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 | x | 3 |
| A | 20 | x | 3 |
| A | 30 | x | 1 |
| B | 10 | x | 1 |
| B | 30 | y | 1 |
| B | 20 | y | 2 |

I've tried rankings, adding supporting columns to do the calculations but is actually stumped as to how to continue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` to compare the values against a slice of the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [ { "Indicator": "A", "Value": 20 }, { "Indicator": "A", "Value": 20 }, { "Indicator": "A", "Value": 30 }, { "Indicator": "B", "Value": 10 }, { "Indicator": "B", "Value": 30 }, { "Indicator": "B", "Value": 20 } ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Rank'] = df.apply(lambda x: (df[df['Indicator'] == x['Indicator']]['Value'] >= x['Value']).sum(), axis=1)
```

result:

|  | Indicator | Value | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 20 | 3 |
| 1 | A | 20 | 3 |
| 2 | A | 30 | 1 |
| 3 | B | 10 | 3 |
| 4 | B | 30 | 1 |
| 5 | B | 20 | 2 |